# How to handle RollbackException caused by ConstraintViolationException with RequestFactory

Tags: hibernate, gwt, jpa, bean-validation, requestfactory

I'm trying to implement a unique value constraint on a field using JPA and Hibernate with RequestFactory (GWT 2.5). My other constraints are implemented using JSR303 and I'd like to report violations to the client in the same way (calling `onConstraintViolation` in the `Receiver`). As I understand, the best option to implement this type of constraint is to set `unique = true` when using the `@Column` attribute. This is then enforced by the database when the transaction is committed and avoids any race conditions associated with asserting the uniqueness via querying.

I followed [this thread's](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/puAoYMDqdF0/FKHh41RH5OAJ) advice on implementing a `ServiceLayerDecorator` to wrap the `invoke` method with a begin and commit of the transaction. If the uniqueness constraint is violated, the commit operation will throw a `RollbackException`.

How do I handle this exception so that it is propagated to the client as a constraint violation instead of a generic failure?

As far as I can tell from looking at `SimpleRequestProcessor`, the validation happens separately to the invocation and there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to propagate failures from `invoke` in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to implement a custom constraint for checking for uniqueness. See also https://community.jboss.org/wiki/AccessingTheHibernateSessionWithinAConstraintValidator.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had considered your approached, but a race condition exists whereby the check might succeed but the commit fail because another transaction committed first and wrote the same value for that field. If only I could have my cake _and_ eat it :)

Comment: Exactly. There is a warning in this regards on the wiki page itself. Just thought I point it out to you. The benefit of course is that you only deal with Bean Validation. If you want one part to be Bean Validation and the other database constraints you indeed want to eat the cake and keep it ;-)

Comment: I took this approach in the end. I think that the UX isn't that bad if the user gets a nondescript error, retries and finds that their item is not unique.